# Libreoffice converter accessibility

Tags: pdf, accessibility, libreoffice, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert an generated Freemarker odt to pdf with help of Libre Office 5 and the console like this: 
"soffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export ".
That already works so far that I get my pdf and also can open/read it.

The point is I need this pdf to be accessibel by screenreaders and such and I searched for a while now and I don't find a way to set an indicated pdf as result this way. There is no problem doing this with the UI version but I need it to work without on a server.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Is it a tagged PDF? Have you tried it in Acrobat's built in voice reader? A good long read about PDF accessibility: https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2017/02/pdf-inaccessibility/ But I can point you to some videos if you want.

Comment: I wanted to get an annotated PDF, but that does not work via console without patching the internal filter. But thanks